# Blender Compressibility Unit Question

Tags: fluid-simulation

What is the unit of compressibility in Blender?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Almost anything can be compressed under the right conditions regardless of whether it is a solid, liquid or gas. Put a different way, if you apply pressure to a liquid, gas, or even many solids their volume will decrease. The amount that the volume will decrease in response to (a certain) pressure is called ["Compressibility"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressibility).

The Blender physics engine can simulate this phenomenon to a limited extent, and the particular value you are asking about is the amount of compression due to gravitational pull. The documentation for this feature is [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/fluid/types/domain.html#fluid-world).

I hope this helps you.